# Browserify + gulp becoming slow

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

We've been using gulp and browserify to create builds of our project whenever a js file changes. As the project has grown this process has become incredibly slow, from 200ms -> ~5s. The project has 69 directories, 173 files, and a max depth of 4 folders. We are applying a few transforms. Here's our build code.

```
var buildJS = function (entryPoint, name, cb) {
    var browserify = require('browserify');
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
    var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
    var reactify = require('reactify');
    var literalify = require('literalify');
    var brfs = require('brfs');

    browserify()
        .require(entryPoint + '/' + name + '.jsx')
        .transform({
           global: true
        }, reactify)
        .transform({
           global: true
        }, brfs)
        .transform({
           global: true
        }, literalify.configure(literalifyConfig))
        .external(config.libs)
        .bundle({
            debug: config.DEV,
            //detectGlobals : false
        })
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulpIf(!config.DEV, uglify()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildPath + '/' + name))
        .on('finish', cb)
};
```

Is this just normal behavior based on our project size? Or are we doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the actual 'size' of the project files. That could amount to a lot of concurrent I/O depending on how you are calling buildJS. Do you have multiple build processes? or is this the only one?

Comment: What i'm trying to say, is do you really need to do all of that 'for development'. Maybe you can alleviate some pain and cut out some of the tasks (leave this build process only for testing/deployment).

Comment: This article suggests using watchify with browserify for incremental builds: http://blog.avisi.nl/2014/04/25/how-to-keep-a-fast-build-with-browserify-and-reactjs/

Comment: There's gulp recipe too: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md

Comment: @livepo The individual files are pretty small, ~300 lines. This build does run alone (whenever we update a js file). This build process is needed since the code is both written in JSX and in node style, so it's unfit to send to the client.

Comment: @Heikki Thanks! I'll try using watchify. I'll answer my own question with your suggestions if it works.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `browserify` always recompile everything. You should be using incremental builds instead if you want good perfs.
I've developed a gulp plugin precisely for that: https://github.com/ngryman/gulp-bro.